# Publishing react app to gitlab using template in backstage

Tags: gitlab, yaml, scaffolding, backstage

I want to use templates in my local backstage and have been trying to publish a *create-react-app* to my gitlab instance, but keep getting the following

> 22022-10-21T22:36:25.000Z HTTPError: Response code 400 (Bad Request)

I have added the integration within my app-config yaml file. There is some connection happening, but seams that I have missed a required attribute for this request. For example, the title for a merge request was not given. A missed a required attribute for this request. For example, the title for a merge request was not given. Wondering whats another required attribute that I am missing for when publishing to gitlab.

```
apiVersion: scaffolder.backstage.io/v1beta3
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: create-react-app-template
  title: Create React App Template
  description: Create a new React website project
  tags:
    - react
    - cra
spec:
  owner: web@example.com
  type: website
  parameters:
    - title: Provide some simple information
      required:
        - component_id
        - owner
      properties:
        component_id:
          title: Name
          type: string
          description: Unique name of the component
          ui:field: EntityNamePicker
        description:
          title: Description
          type: string
          description: Help others understand what this website is for.
        owner:
          title: Owner
          type: string
          description: Owner of the component
          ui:field: OwnerPicker
          ui:options:
            allowedKinds:
              - Group
    - title: Choose a location
      required:
        - repoUrl
      properties:
        repoUrl:
          title: Repository Location
          type: string
          ui:field: RepoUrlPicker
          ui:options:
            allowedHosts:
              - gitlab.example.com

  steps:
    - id: template
      name: Fetch Skeleton + Template
      action: fetch:template
      input:
        url: ./skeleton
        copyWithoutRender:
          - .github/workflows/*
        values:
          component_id: ${{ parameters.component_id }}
          description: ${{ parameters.description }}
          destination: ${{ parameters.repoUrl | parseRepoUrl }}
          owner: ${{ parameters.owner }}

    - id: publish
      name: Publish
      action: publish:gitlab
      input:
        allowedHosts:
          - gitlab.example.com
        description: This is ${{ parameters.component_id }}
        repoUrl: ${{ parameters.repoUrl }}
        title: Creating catalog-info.yaml ${{ parameters.name }} for backstage

    - id: register
      name: Register
      action: catalog:register
      input:
        repoContentsUrl: ${{ steps.publish.output.repoContentsUrl }}
        catalogInfoPath: "/catalog-info.yaml"

  output:
    links:
      - title: Repository
        url: ${{ steps.publish.output.remoteUrl }}
      - title: Open in catalog
        icon: catalog
        entityRef: ${{ steps.register.output.entityRef }}
```

When I want to go through the template of the Create React App it creates a

> Repo Url -> gitlab.example.com?owner=maxbojorquez&repo=template